# Heat equation with the Crank-Nicolson method on MATLAB

Tags: matlab, differential-equations

I am trying to implement the crank nicolson method in matlab of this equation :

```
du/dt-d²u/dx²=f(x,t)
u(0,t)=u(L,t)=0
u(x,0)=u0(x)
```

with  :

```
- f(x,t)=20*exp(-50(x-1/2)²) if t<1/2; elso f(x,t)=0
- (x,t) belong to [0,L] x R+
```

The boundary conditions are :

```
- U0(x)=0
- L = 1
- T = 1
```

Here is my mathematical thinking:

[image: crank-nicolson equation]

[image: system to solve]

```
of the form A*Un+1=B*Un+ht/2*Fn
```

My problem is that I get inconsistent results and I can't find my mistake. My graph is made up of positive and negative peaks, which is totally wrong in relation to the equation

Here is my code:

```
%Parameters discretization in space according to the variable x
Nx=50; %Number of intervals, we will have Nx+1 discretization points
L=1; %Wire length
hx = 1/Nx ; %  Step of discretization in space
Xx = hx*[0:Nx]' ;    % Vector of discretized space

%Parameters discretization in space according to the variable t
Nt=200; %Number of intervals, we will have Ny+1 discretization points
T=1; %Time for which the heat propagation will be simulated
ht = 1/Nt ; %  Step of discretization in time
Xt = ht*[0:Nt]' ;    % Vector of discretized time

F=zeros(Nx+1,Nt+1); %Creation of the matrix that will contain the values of the function F(x,t)

for i=1:(Nt/2-1)
    F(:,i)=20*exp(-50*([0:hx:L]-1/2).^2); %Insertion in the matrix of the function F(x,t)=20*exp(-50(x-1/2)²) if t<1/2 and 0 otherwise
end

U=zeros(Nx+1,Nt+1); %Creation of the matrix that will contain the solutions of the equation

A=(1+2*alpha)*diag(ones(1,Nx+1))-alpha*diag(ones(1,Nx),1)-alpha*diag(ones(1,Nx),-1);
A(1,:)=0; %Zeroing of the first line, to enter the boundary conditions
A(end,:)=0; %Zeroing the last line to enter the boundary conditions
A(1,1)=1; %Boundary condition
A(end,end)=1; %Boundary condition

B=(1-2*alpha)*diag(ones(1,Nx+1))+alpha*diag(ones(1,Nx),1)+alpha*diag(ones(1,Nx),-1); %We write in the matrix B the terms which are repeated on the diagonals
B(1,:)=0; %Zeroing of the first line, to enter the boundary conditions
B(end,:)=0; %Zeroing the last line to enter the boundary conditions
B(1,1)=1; %Boundary condition
B(end,end)=1; %Boundary condition


for i = 1:(Nt)
    U(:,i+1)=((B*U(:,i)+(ht/2)*F(:,i)+(ht/2)*F(:,i+1))\A); %Iterative resolution of the system, we advance by one time step at each loop
end

surf(Xt,Xx,U)
xlabel("t");
ylabel("x");
title("Temperature distribution in the wire as a function of time")
shading interp
```

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZNhf.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your detailed post, however, what is your question? You haven't asked one. Could you please [edit] your post to add your question?

Comment: Hello, I just modified my question, I can't see why I get completely crazy results

Comment: You are using constantly `(ht/ht^2)` where you certainly wanted to use `(ht/hx^2)` or even better `alpha=0.5*ht/hx^2`. Does this give a more expected result?

Comment: Thank you, indeed I had an error in this alpha coefficient, I just corrected the code but I still get the same result, I added a photo at the end of the question. My boundary conditions for my discretization in space must not be good.

Comment: Could you check the definition of matrix operations? As far as I understand it, `M\A` "M below A on the left" denotes `M^{-1}*A`, if necessary with using the pseudo-inverse. What you want from the theory `A*U(:,i+1)=M=B*U(:,i)+...` is `U(:,i+1)=A\M`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution of a linear system `A*x=b` is denoted in Matlab as

```
x = A\b;
```

"A to the left of b in denominator position", that is, `A^(-1)*b` (employing pseudo-inverses if necessary).

Applying this correction,

```
for i = 1:(Nt)
    U(:,i+1)=A\(B*U(:,i)+(ht/2)*F(:,i)+(ht/2)*F(:,i+1)); 
end
```

results in the solution

[image: plot of the time evolution]